# Python MD5 cracker improvement

Tags: python, python-3.x, md5

I was just writing a very simple MD5 cracker in python. What it does is loads 2 wordlists. 1 wordlist from `pass.txt` in clear text and other list from `hash.txt` with all MD5 hashes. It takes the clear text passwords and generates a MD5 hash line by line and compares to all MD5 in `hash.txt`. The cracker works fine, so far it works as intended, but my question is if it can be improved. Let's say can it be faster or if I load a huge list in it with millions of passwords, can that be an issue on resources? Etc. Or even the mechanics of comparing the strings.

Code:

```
def clear_pass():
with open("pass.txt", "r", encoding="latin-1") as file:
    for x in file:
        x = x.strip()
        #print(x)
        str2hash = (x)
        result = hashlib.md5(str2hash.encode())
        final_result = (result.hexdigest())
        #print(final_result)
        with open("hash.txt", "r") as hash_file:
            for z in hash_file:
                z = z.strip()
                if z == final_result:
                    print("[+] " + final_result+ " :", x)
clear_pass()
```

[image]

Comment: At the moment your program only cracks one of your passwords at a time, using one CPU core. You can try using multiprocessing (using multiple cores at the same time) to get a speed-up that way. Using [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) with the ProcessPoolExecutor might be a good place to start.

Comment: Also, you are doing a linear search through all the hashes in hash.txt for each password lookup. This takes O(n) time. It would be faster to load all the hashes into a dict first - that will save you the overhead of reading the file, and will be a constant time O(1) lookup. If you have too many hashes to load into memory, then you can use a database instead; indexing your database will give you O(log n) time.

Comment: thanks, I will look into that too, this looks interesting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program is a doubly nested for loop.  That's pretty terrible.  For each word that you calculate that hash value of, you're then reading the entire file hash.txt.  You're reading that file over and over again.

You should instead do something like:

```
hash_to_string = {}
with open("pass.txt", "r", encoding="latin-1") as file:
    for x in file:
        ... strip it.  Generate md5.  Call results hash...
        hash_to_string[hash] = x
with open("hash.txt") as hash_file:
    for x in file:
        if x.strip() is a key in the hash_to_string table, you've got the plain text
        otherwise, you're done.
```

Your code is now linear rather than O(n^2).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I followed the answer and almost finished it. For some reason in the last step, I don't get anything out: 
```with open("hash.txt") as hash_file: for z in hash_file:  if z.strip() in hash_to_string:``` Is it maybe because the dict is not converted?

Comment: By the way, my "otherwise you're done" was meant to be mean "look at the next hash value", not "return None".  Have you tried putting the hash value of something you *know* is in pass.txt into hash.txt?  That'll let you know if you're code is working correctly or not.

Comment: I can print all the values from dictionary in the first part of code, but what ever I do in the second part nothing happens, not even an error message. I put in both lists valid values, that I know this hash is this pass

Comment: The key in the dictionary was in some way subtlely different that the key you were reading from the file?  (An extra newline?  Uppercase vs. lowercase?). Just curious.

Comment: No they were exactly same. I also convert the hashes to .lower() just in case. But it seems like it may not be reading from dictionary for some reason, it still takes a long time with big dict. Would you mind posting the code how it's supposes to look? Thanks

Comment: You're going to have to hash each of your plaintexts once.  There really isn't any way to speed that up.